# Hibernate : HQL query to directly compare timestamp from database value

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql, spring-mvc, hql

- I am working on a Spring-MVC application using Hibernate as ORM and PostgreSQL database, in which I am saving in a
  database row some values(obvious). With that information, I am also
  saving the TimeStamp(java.sql.TimeStamp) when the entry was made. For
  some reasons I want to remove entries which are older than 5 minutes.

How is it possible for me to give an HQL query with Timestamp,    something like if timestamp>oldTimestamp then delete that row. I have    something like this till now :

```
 @Override
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 100000)
    public void removeStaleLocks() {
        session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    //Timestamp timestamp = // current timestamp;
        Query query = session.createQuery("delete from NoteLock as nl where nl.timeStamp=:timeStamp");
        query.setParameter("timeStamp",timeStamp);
        query.executeUpdate();
        session.flush();
    }
```

What I would like to do is pass the query a parameter as use this as current timestamp denoting this is the currentTime, and delete all notes which are more than 5 minutes old. Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry for the weird subject line, didn't knew what to write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
long nowMinus5Minutes = now - (5L * 60L * 1000L);
Timestamp nowMinus5MinutesAsTimestamp = new Timestamp(nowMinus5Minutes);

Query query = session.createQuery("delete from NoteLock as nl where nl.timeStamp < :limit");
query.setParameter("limit", nowMinus5MinutesAsTimestamp);
query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Better use
`long nowMinus5Minutes = now - Duration.ofMinutes(5).toMillis();`
to avoid calculation of nanoseconds with magic numbers.